# Parent state not changing from child component function

Tags: reactjs

I have seen the various methods of changing the state of a parent by passing down the function and updating it in the child.  I have passed the function down successfully, however, the state of the parent does not change on my onClick event.  The Parent component does rerender as I am able to see in console.log.  Also, I am using a functional component as the child, however, I did try changing it to a class based component with no luck (don't wanna lose my hooks).  Here is the parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import SwipeableDrawer from '@material-ui/core/SwipeableDrawer';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import { Grid, Paper } from '@material-ui/core'
import SideNavBar from '../containers/SideNavBar';
const styles = {
    list: {
        width: 250,
    },
    fullList: {
        width: 'auto',
    },
};
class Header extends React.Component {
    state = {
        left: false
    }
    toggleDrawer = (side, open) => () => {
        this.setState({
            [side]: open,
        });
    };
    render() {
        console.log(this.state)
        const { classes } = this.props;
        const sideList = (
            <SideNavBar toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer} />
        );
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log(this.state)}
                <div className='headerroot'>
                    <Grid container spacing={0}>
                        <Grid item sm={1} xl={1}>
                            <div className='headericondiv'>
                                <i className="material-icons md-24" onClick={this.toggleDrawer('left', true)}>dehaze</i>
                            </div>
                            <SwipeableDrawer
                                open={this.state.left}
                                onClose={this.toggleDrawer('left', false)}
                                onOpen={this.toggleDrawer('left', true)}
                            >
                                <SideNavBar toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer} />
                            </SwipeableDrawer>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs>
                            <div className='headertitle'>Solutions Hub</div>
                        </Grid>
                        <Grid item xs>
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <div className='sitetop' />




                </div>

            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

And the child:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import SideBarNavLink from './SideBarNavLink'
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import LogoutButton from '../usercomponents/LogoutButton';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

const SideNavBar = (props) => {
    const [ticketLinks, openTicketLinks] = useState(false)
    const [adminLinks, openAdminLinks] = useState(false)
    let ticketNav, adminNav = null
    if (ticketLinks) {
        ticketNav = (
            <div>
                ticketLinks
            </div>
        )
    }
    if (adminLinks) {
        adminNav = (
            <div>
                adminNav
            </div>
        )
    }
    const closeDrawer = () => props.toggleDrawer('left', false)
    console.log(props.toggleDrawer)
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className='linksroot'>
                <Link to='/' onClick={closeDrawer}>
                    <div className='iniitiallink' >
                        Home
                    </div>
                </Link>
                <Link to='/createticket/' >
                    <div className='iniitiallink'>
                        Create a Ticket
                </div>
                </Link>
                <div className='iniitiallink'>
                    My Open Tickets
            </div>
                <div className='iniitiallink' onClick={() => openTicketLinks(!ticketLinks)}>
                    Tickets
            </div>
                <div>
                    {ticketNav}
                </div>
                <div className='iniitiallink' onClick={() => openAdminLinks(!adminLinks)}>
                    Admin
            </div>
                <div>
                    {adminNav}
                </div>
                <div className='buttonroot' style={{
                    paddingBottom: '1.2rem',
                    paddingLeft: '1.2rem'
                }}>
                    <LogoutButton />
                </div>
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

export default withRouter(SideNavBar)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`toggleDrawer` is a function that returns a function. So instead of `const closeDrawer = () => props.toggleDrawer('left', false)` try `const closeDrawer = props.toggleDrawer('left', false)`.

Comment: Dead gum you are good.  Thank you sir.  If you have time could you give me a brief explanation why in this case I don't need a function?  Every other question asked had this something more like this in the child.  this.props.onSelectLanguage(lang)

Comment: I understand the toggledrawer returns a function part.

Comment: What `closeDrawer` was doing is calling `props.toggleDrawer()`, but then not calling the function that it returns (which in the one that calls `setState`). `() => props.toggleDrawer('left', false)()` would also work but that would unnecessarily create a new function on every click. Hence the above